# Scrape full size pictures from website that are not ON the main page

Tags: python, web-scraping

Here's the website I'm talking about: https://forums.redflagdeals.com/costco-costco-east-brossard-bridge-candiac-sherbooke-march-01-march-07-2021-apple-juice-edition-2448703/

The full-size picture is in the "inline attachments" https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS7gp.jpg

I was thinking to open each picture individually chrome (get. chrome) but I'm sure there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I think you should just Loop through all the `<div class=inline-attachment>` divs or the `<div class=thumbnail>` divs in the page.